# Disable warning lint for a method in external library in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

In my Android project I have an external library with following method:

```
// Some external library
class Foo {
    @CheckReturnValue
    public final Bar returnBar(Bar bar) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have to call this method a lot in my project, but I do not need the returned value of this method. All I need is the side effect of the method. So this is how I use it:

```
fooInstance.returnBar(barInstance) // ignore returned value
```

The problem with the above code is that Android Studio editor will show `CheckResult` warning lint. What I can do is to either just live with that warning lint or disable `CheckResult` for the entire project or module, but I was wondering if there is a better approach to this warning.

What I cannot do is to put `SuppressLint` because I will be using that method 100 < times in my project and adding `SuppressLint` to every single usage is not really feasible.

I already went through Android Studio inspection settings but unfortunately was not able to find anything that can help. I would be grateful if you could provide literally any thought on this problem.

Comment: How about having one static method that calls the library method? If you do that, you can do "SuppressLint" on that static method and call that static method 100 times in your code.

Comment: @THEPATEL, Thank you for your suggestion. I was trying to avoid that approach because the library uses a lot of [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) like `Glide` and `RxJava` and it would look bad if a part of the chain is written somewhere else. But I will surely try what you suggested cause it looks like there is no other way to avoid the lint.